Is user-defined code navigation supported in Visual Studio Code?
In Visual Studio Code, while working on a bug fix, I often need to navigate through a lot of code and files. I’d like to save my code navigation path so I can reload it later and easily resume navigation using Alt+LeftArrow and Alt+RightArrow. I’ve looked into existing extensions like bookmarks and numbered bookmarks but haven't found exactly what I need.
